# Display html code, not the tags

Tags: html

I am using a theme and I want to modify it in order to use html code in a text field.

This is the part of the code that renders this field:

```
do_shortcode( wpautop( esc_html( $sectionData['left-content'] ) ) )
```

I want to modify it in order to display html code properly, but it keeps rendering the tags and not the formatted text.

I want to display **this** but it displays `<b>this</b>`. How I can modify it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the `esc_html()`. The whole purpose of that function is to prevent text being interpreted as HTML.

```
do_shortcode( wpautop( $sectionData['left-content'] ) );
```